# Create matrix to count occurrence of elements for each column x index pair

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                  'Call_loc': ['SJDR', 'SJDR', 'SJDR', 'TR', 'LD', 'LD'],
                  'Time_Range': [0,0,1,2,23,41]})
```

I need create an array `Call_loc` x `Time_Range` to count the number of occurrences of an `Id` for each pair of `Call_loc` and `Time_Range`. An output for `Id` 1 would look like this:

```
     SJDR | TR | LD
0  |  2   |  0 | 0
1  |  0   |  0 | 0
2  |  0   |  0 | 0
23 |  0   |  0 | 0
41 |  0   |  0 | 0
```

I believe that the ideal for this situation would be to create a dictionary where the key would be the Id and the values the arrays. However, I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help? I'm trying this, but without sucess:

```
dict_matrix = {}
for x in df['Id']:
    df_aux = df.loc[df['Id'] == x]
    dict_matrix[x] = pd.crosstab(df_aux.Time_Range, df_aux.Call_loc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

- Group the dataframe by columns `Id`, `Call_loc` and `Time_Range` and aggregate using `size` to count the occurrence of the columns `Id`, `Call_loc` and `Time_Range` together.
- Now, we have reindex the dataframe in order to ensure that each combination of the above three columns is present is the dataframe, and wherever the combination is absent we add that combination and fill the corresponding count with `0`. This is basically a reindexing operation which can be done by reshaping the dataframe with `unstack` followed by `stack`

```py
s = df.groupby([*df.columns]).size()
s = s.unstack([1, 2]).stack(dropna=False)\
                     .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

**Alternatively**, here is another way to reindex the dataframe

```
s = df.groupby([*df.columns]).size()
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels)
s = s.reindex(i, fill_value=0).unstack(1)
```

##### Result

```
>>> s

Call_loc       LD  SJDR  TR
Id Time_Range              
1  0            0     2   0
   1            0     0   0
   2            0     0   0
   23           0     0   0
   41           0     0   0
2  0            0     0   0
   1            0     1   0
   2            0     0   1
   23           0     0   0
   41           0     0   0
3  0            0     0   0
   1            0     0   0
   2            0     0   0
   23           1     0   0
   41           1     0   0

>>> s.loc[1] # For Id=1

Call_loc    LD  SJDR  TR
Time_Range              
0            0     2   0
1            0     0   0
2            0     0   0
23           0     0   0
41           0     0   0

>>> s.loc[2] # For Id=2

Call_loc    LD  SJDR  TR
Time_Range              
0            0     0   0
1            0     1   0
2            0     0   1
23           0     0   0
41           0     0   0
```